# Do State-of-the-art and Cutting edge have the same meaning?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Do *state-of-the-art* and *cutting edge* mean the same thing or do they have different meanings? If they have different meanings, which is used when?

Comment: I am not a native speaker of English, so please excuse me for grammatical mistakes,punctuation mistakes etc.

Comment: There is no sharp distinction here, but just based on the metaphor, one could argue CE is somewhat more advanced than SotA, albeit riskier. The phrase SotA describes the best *generally available* technology; where the world has advanced to, to date. By contrast, the metaphor CE evokes the image of the sharp, extreme *edge* of the knife. The outermost perimeter. In my mind this conjures notions of extremity and therefore experimental, less well-established (and therefore riskier) technology. By way of example: I'd happy take a SotA medical treatment .... less so a CE one.

Comment: (There's also the phrase *bleeding edge*, which connotes something even ... edgier? ... than *cutting edge*. Again, these shades of meaning derive from the imagery employed: certainly something which has *blood* on it is both super sharp and very *risky*.)

Comment: As stated, the meanings are slightly different. "State of the art" is the best and most recent of well-established practice.  "Cutting edge" implies something that is not yet well-established and hence may not work right or may be completely discarded for something better before it achieves "state of the art" status.

Comment: It seems to me that a craftsman might produce a manually operated butter churn whose high-quality materials, sturdy design, and adoption of the best features of various nineteenth-century models qualified it as "state of the art" ("best of breed," as some technology magazines put it) today, without its being in any practical sense "cutting edge" ("ahead of the competition in technology or design").

Answer (score 5):

"State of the art" is used to describe the best in the specified field.

"Cutting edge" is the newest, and mostly likely still has problems to be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

**'State-of-the-art'** is '**the best already produced'**, something that is the best and implemented. The term usually describes a product.

**'Cutting edge'** is '**leading**', latest trend and achievement. The term is used to describe technology.

Answer (score -2):

["state-of-the-art"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/state-of-the-art): the latest and most sophisticated or advanced stage of a technology, art, or science.

["cutting edge"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cutting%20edge?s=t): the leading position in any field; forefront

They can be used interchangeably in most circumstances, but the difference is "State of the art" is generally the most advanced of all the technology, while "cutting edge" would connotate brand new technology.